# All values popping up on end time

Tags: python, dictionary, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

events=[]
start_dates=[{'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"a"', 'id': '1', 'status': 'confirmed', 'htmlLink': 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=a', 'created': '2022-02-15T20:49:40.000Z', 'updated': '2022-02-15T20:49:40.810Z', 'summary': 'First day', 'creator': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'organizer': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'start': {'date': '2022-02-06'}, 'end': {'date': '2022-02-08'}, 'transparency': 'transparent', 'iCalUID': '1@google.com', 'sequence': 0, 'reminders': {'useDefault': False}, 'eventType': 'default'}]
```

I am trying to convert start_dates into dateTime by using/removing the ['start]['date'] and ['end']['date'] then localizing it into a timezone from there splitting it off into days.
**For some reason it only adds to the last day so multiple events in one day which should be on seperate days.** Dictionary appending only happens for the last element.

```
    tz='America/Vancouver'
    time_zone = pytz.timezone(tz)
    for event in start_dates:
        new_start_time = datetime.strptime(event['start']['date'], '%Y-%m-%d' )
        new_end_time = datetime.strptime(event['end']['date'], '%Y-%m-%d' ) 
        #Loop through each day
        del event['start']['date']
        del event['end']['date']
        while new_start_time < new_end_time:
            print(new_start_time,new_end_time)
            vancouver_time = time_zone.localize(new_start_time)
            print(vancouver_time)
            #Append to events to create a day long datetime for calendar.html or multiple time slots for bookappointment
            #The end date is just the current day
            event['start']['dateTime'] = vancouver_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
            event['end']['dateTime'] = (vancouver_time+relativedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
            event['start']['timeZone'] = tz
            event['end']['timeZone'] = tz
            print(event)
            events.append(event)
            for delta in range(0, 30 * 48, 30):
                offsetted_ist = vancouver_time + timedelta(minutes=delta)
                print("Date & Time in :", offsetted_ist.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))

            new_start_time= new_start_time+relativedelta(days=1)
    # Make multiple hour datetimes into 30 min chunks and convert timezone if any
    print(events)
```

Does display the right start and end dates for each.

```
{'kind': 'calendar#event', 'etag': '"a"', 'id': '1', 'status': 'confirmed', 'htmlLink': 'https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=a', 'created': '2022-02-19T20:48:56.000Z', 'updated': '2022-02-19T20:48:56.482Z', 'creator': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'organizer': {'email': 'a@hotmail.com', 'self': True}, 'start': {'dateTime': '2022-02-06T00:00:00-0800', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'end': {'dateTime': '2022-02-07T00:00:00-0800', 'timeZone': 'America/Vancouver'}, 'transparency': 'transparent', 'iCalUID': '1@google.com', 'sequence': 0, 'reminders': {'useDefault': False}, 'eventType': 'default'}
```

The below grabs all of them on the same day.

```
events_per_day = list(filter(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['start']['dateTime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').day == day, events))
```